# Unix/Perl/Python: substitute list on big data set

Tags: awk, language-agnostic

I've got a mapping file of about 13491 key/value pairs which I need to use to replace the key with the value in a data set of about 500000 lines divided over 25 different files.

Example mapping:
`value1,value2`

Example input: `field1,field2,**value1**,field4`

Example output: `field1,field2,**value2**,field4`

Please note that the value could be in different places on the line with more than 1 occurrence.

My current approach is with AWK:

`awk -F, 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2 ; next } { for (i in a) gsub(i, a[i]); print }' mapping.txt file1.txt > file1_mapped.txt`

However, this is taking a very long time.

Is there any other way to make this faster? Could use a variety of tools (Unix, AWK, Sed, Perl, Python etc.)

Comment: I can't reliably compare my posted program's performance with your `awk` line without realistic data. So I'm expecting you to let me know if my program does or doesn't improve your runtimes :)

Comment: Would you be so kind as to test my Perl solution as well and tell us which solution is fastest and the times? See also commentary under my answer.

Comment: @AlexHarvey, your solution takes `6m37.220s` on a single file containing 17576 lines. I like your solution as it goes through the entire line not taking separated fields into account but it is significantly slower than @zdim's solution: `0m0.419s`

Comment: `500000` lines should ring alarm bells for you if you ever plan to use `awk` for such files. For simple substitutions `sed` would be pretty, *or at the least considerably*, fast for such files. However, `sed`'s abilities are limited and it typically suits basic search and replace for systems administration.

Comment: @Subbeh to provide the right answer we'd need to know some more about your requirements, including 1) do you want a regexp or string match (e.g should `a.c` match `abc` or ONLY `a.c`), and 2) do you want a partial or full match (e.g. should `foo1` match the first 4 chars of `foo12` or ONLY `foo1` as a complete field)? If you post a few lines of sample input and epected output that cover all of your use cases (including where you have multiple strings on 1 line to replace and strings that should NOT be replaced such as regexp or partial matches if those are undesirable) then we can help you.

Comment: @sjsam Huh? Awk can handle files of 500000 lines as efficiently as any other tool, more so usually since manipulating text is ALL that awk was created to do and so it is highly optimized for just that specific task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**   See the second part for a version that uses `Text::CSV` module to parse files

---

Load mappings into a hash (dictionary), then go through your files and test each field for whether there is such a key in the hash, replace with value if there is. Write each line out to a temporary file, and when done move it into a new file (or overwrite the processed file).  Any tool has to do that, more or less.

With Perl, tested with a few small made-up files

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use File::Copy qw(move);

my $file = shift;
die "Usage: $0 mapping-file data-files\n"  if not $file or not @ARGV;

my %map;
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
while (<$fh>) { 
    my ($key, $val) = map { s/^\s+|\s+$//gr } split /\s*,\s*/;  # see Notes
    $map{$key} = $val;
}

my $outfile = "tmp.outfile.txt.$$";  # but better use File::Temp

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    open my $fh_out, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";
    open my $fh,     '<', $file    or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    while (<$fh>) {
        s/^\s+|\s+$//g;               # remove leading/trailing whitespace
        my @fields = split /\s*,\s*/;
        exists($map{$_}) && ($_=$map{$_}) for @fields;  # see Notes
        say $fh_out join ',', @fields;
    }   
    close $fh_out;

    # Change to commented out line once thoroughly tested
    #move($outfile, $file) or die "can't move $outfile to $file: $!";
    move($outfile, 'new_'.$file) or die "can't move $outfile: $!";
}
```

Notes.

- The check of data against mappings is written for efficiency: We must look at each field, there's no escaping that, but then we only check for the field as a key (no regex). For this all leading/trailing spaces need be stripped. Thus this code may change whitespace in output data files; in case this is important for some reason it can of course be modified to preserve original spaces.
- It came up in comments that a field in data can differ in fact, by having extra quotes. Then extract the would-be key first

  ```
    for (@fields) {
        $_ = $map{$1}  if /"?([^"]*)/ and exists $map{$1};
    }
  ```

  This starts the regex engine on every check, what affects efficiency. It would help to clean up that input CSV data of quotes instead, and run with the code as it is above, with no regex. This can be done by reading files using a CSV-parsing module; see comment at the end.
- For Perls earlier than 5.14 replace

  ```
    my ($key, $val) = map { s/^\s+|\s+$//gr } split /\s*,\s*/;
  ```

  with

  ```
    my ($key, $val) = map { s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_ } split /\s*,\s*/;
  ```

  since the "non-destructive" `/r` modifier was introduced only [in v5.14](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Regular-Expressions)
- If you'd rather that your whole operation doesn't die for one bad file, replace `or die ...` with

  ```
    or do { 
        # print warning for whatever failed (warn "Can't open $file: $!";)
        # take care of filehandles and such if/as needed
        next;
    };
  ```

  and make sure to (perhaps log and) review output.

This leaves room for some efficiency improvements, but nothing dramatic.

---

The data, with commas separating fields, may (or may not) be valid CSV. Since the question doesn't at all address this, and doesn't report problems, it is unlikely that any properties of the CSV data format are used in data files (delimiters embedded in data, protected quotes).

However, it's still a good idea to read these files using a module that honors full CSV, like [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). That also makes things easier, by  taking care of extra spaces and quotes and handing us cleaned-up fields.  So here's that -- the same as above, but using the module to parse files

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use File::Copy qw(move);

use Text::CSV;

my $file = shift;
die "Usage: $0 mapping-file data-files\n"  if not $file or not @ARGV;
    
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1, allow_whitespace => 1 } ) 
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag ();

my %map;
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
while (my $line = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    $map{ $line->[0] } = $line->[1]
}

my $outfile = "tmp.outfile.txt.$$";  # use File::Temp    

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    open my $fh_out, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";
    open my $fh,     '<', $file    or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    while (my $line = $csv->getline($fh)) {
        exists($map{$_}) && ($_=$map{$_}) for @$line;
        say $fh_out join ',', @$line;
    }
    close $fh_out;

    move($outfile, 'new_'.$file) or die "Can't move $outfile: $!";
}
```

Now we don't have to worry about spaces or overall quotes at all, what simplifies things a bit.

While it is difficult to reliably compare these two approaches without realistic data files, I benchmarked them for (made-up) large data files that involve "similar" processing. The code using `Text::CSV` for parsing runs either around the same, or (up to) 50% faster.

The constructor option  [allow_whitespace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#allow_whitespace) makes it *remove* extra spaces, perhaps contrary to what the name may imply, as I do by hand above. (Also see `allow_loose_quotes` and related options.) There is far more, see docs. The `Text::CSV` defaults to [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS), if installed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193762/discussion-on-answer-by-zdim-unix-perl-python-substitute-list-on-big-data-set).

Comment: @Subbeh Added a version that uses `Text::CSV` (a standard for these things) to read (valid CSV) files.  This takes care of possible quotes and spaces so it's a little simpler as well.  Testing reliably is hard without real data but I found this to perhaps be faster, up to around 50%. So it may be worth a try.  (If you do, I'd love to know how it compares with hand-rolled one, on your real data.)

Answer (score 5):

You're doing 13,491 `gsub()`s on every one of your 500,000 input lines - that's almost 7 billion full-line regexp search/replaces total. So yes, that would take some time and it's almost certainly corrupting your data in ways you just haven't noticed as the result of one gsub() gets changed by the next gsub() and/or you get partial replacements!

I saw in a comment that some of your fields can be surrounded by double quotes. If those fields can't contain commas or newlines and assuming you want full string matches then this is how to write it:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    map[$1] = $2
    map["\""$1"\""] = "\""$2"\""
    next
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i in map) {
            $i = map[$i]
        }
    }
    print
}
```

I tested the above on a mapping file with 13,500 entries and an input file of 500,000 lines with multiple matches on most lines in cygwin on my underpowered laptop and it completed in about 1 second:

```
$ wc -l mapping.txt
13500 mapping.txt

$ wc -l file500k
500000 file500k

$ time awk -f tst.awk mapping.txt file500k > /dev/null
real    0m1.138s
user    0m1.109s
sys     0m0.015s
```

If that doesn't do exactly what you want efficiently then please edit your question to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clearer requirements, see [my comment under your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248555/unix-perl-python-substitute-list-on-big-data-set#comment99129290_56248555).

Comment: A nice demonstration of the elegance of AWK relative to Perl. ;-) I think you could improve the readability by defining a variable `quote = "\""` and then having `map[quote $1 quote] = quote $2 quote` ?

Comment: Thanks. I find hard-coding `"\""` more readable especially in some other contexts (I like to stick to one way of doing things like this and `\047` vs `'` vs `quote="'"`) such as `$0 ~ "\"foo\""` vs `$0 ~ quote foo quote` where I'm not even sure if the latter would be interpreted as `($0 ~ quote) foo quote` or `$0 ~ (quote foo quote)` but YMMV I suppose.

Comment: Arrgh I got the code wrong, it should be `$0 ~ quote "foo" quote` (apparently not only do I struggle to read it but I can't write it either :-) ) but you get the idea.

Comment: @Subbeh you're welcome. I'd be very interested in seeing the timing differences between the awk and perl solutions when run against your real data if you wouldn't mind updating your question to show them (just run `time awk ...` and `time perl ...` to get them but use the 3rd-run timing from each to eliminate cacheing impacts). If you do that then please leave me a comment so I can check it out. Thanks,.

Comment: @AlexHarvey sorry I forgot to tag you in the above comments. Clearly I need some coffee.

Answer (score 1):

There is some commentary below suggesting that the OP needs to handle real CSV data, whereas the question says:

> Please note that the value could be in different places on the line with more than 1 occurrence.

I have taken this to mean that these are lines, not CSV data, and that a regex-based solution is required. The OP also confirmed that interpretation in a comment above.

As noted in other answers, however, it is faster to break the data into fields and simply lookup the replacement in the map.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Load mappings.txt into a Perl
# Hash %m.
#
open my $mh, '<', './mappings.txt'
  or die "open: $!";

my %m = ();
while ($mh) {
  chomp;
  my @f = split ',';
  $m{$f[0]} = $f[1];
}

# Load files.txt into a Perl
# Array @files.
#
open my $fh, '<', './files.txt';
chomp(my @files = $fh);

# Update each file line by line,
# using a temporary file similar
# to sed -i.
#
foreach my $file (@files) {

  open my $fh, '<', $file
    or die "open: $!";
  open my $th, '>', "$file.bak"
    or die "open: $!";

  while ($fh) {
    foreach my $k (keys %m) {
      my $v = $m[$k];
      s/\Q$k/$v/g;
    }
    print $th;
  }

  rename "$file.bak", $file
    or die "rename: $!";
}
```

I assume of course that you have your mappings in `mappings.txt` and file list in `files.txt`.

Comment: That `%m` is the whole mapping, with those "13491" keys. So the code runs a regex _for each key_, on each line of data. That will actually and visibly hurt runtime, while it's not needed -- the code isn't _using_ the hash but is checking for every single key.

Comment: Speed only matters if it works, but your solution replaces sequences that are only part of fields. It also fails to handle CSV quoting and escaping. (Proper handling of CSV is required according to comments by the OP.)

Comment: @ikegami, I think you didn't read the OP's post carefully enough. They say, "Please note that the value could be in different places on the *line* with more than 1 occurrence." They don't say that values must take up the entire field. Also, the pattern `**value1**` and `**value2**` to me looks like it is chosen because the data otherwise will not contain their delimiters, `**`. If so, my code works fine. And, obviously, it is trivial to fix if my assumption there is incorrect.

Comment: Re "*They don't say that values must take up the entire field.*", The Question would lead you to believe that, and the fact that zdim's solution works proves it

Comment: Re "*to me looks like it is chosen because the data otherwise will not contain their delimiters, \*\*.*", Oh, I hadn't even brought up the issue of your code injection because I was planning on fixing it. Fixed now.

Comment: Well the OP's comment explicitly confirmed that they prefer a line-based solution, although mine is too slow, so I did read the question correctly. @ikegami. I'll have to have a think to see if it can be sped up.

Comment: Re "*Well the OP's comment explicitly confirmed*", Where? I see a place where they said their failed attempt did it that way because they didn't know how to handle CSV properly. This is a bug in their solution too

Comment: @ikegami, "_I like your solution as it goes through the entire line not taking separated fields into account but it is significantly slower than zdim's solution_". So I guess you're saying their requirements are wrong?

Comment: No,I'm saying they're right, and that your solution doesn't comply to them in numerous ways. Even if you're right about this part, it's just that, a part.

Comment: @ikegami, well, you have stated, "_It seems you want match entire fields_", and as I pointed out, it doesn't say that, and what it does say appears to contradict that, namely, "_Please note that the value could be in different places on the line with more than 1 occurrence._"

Comment: @ikegami, what are the other "numerous ways" that this solution, which I tested, "doesn't comply"?

Comment: This code has a few basic issues: open and rename need to be checked for errors, lexical handles should be used instead of barewords, and each should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks @Grinnz. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, you have proper CSV. The following properly handles quoting and escapes when reading from the map file, when reading from a data file, and when writing to a data file.

It seems you want match entire fields. The following does this. It even supports fields that contains commas (`,`) and/or quotes (`"`). It does the comparisons using a hash lookup, which is much faster than a regex match.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ auto_diag => 2, binary => 1 });

sub process {
   my ($map, $in_fh, $out_fh) = @_;
   while ( my $row = $csv->getline($in_fh) ) {
      $csv->say($out_fh, [ map { $map->{$_} // $_ } @$row ]);
   }
}

die "usage: $0 {map} [{file} [...]]\n"
   if @ARGV < 1;

my $map_qfn = shift;

my %map;
{
   open(my $fh, '<', $map_qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$map_qfn\": $!\n");
   while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
      $map{$row->[0]} = $row->[1];
   }
}

if (@ARGV) {
   for my $qfn (@ARGV) {
      open(my $in_fh, '<', $qfn)
         or warn("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n"), next;
      rename($qfn, $qfn."~")
         or warn("Can't rename \"$qfn\": $!\n"), next;
      open(my $out_fh, '>', $qfn)
         or warn("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n"), next;
      eval { process(\%map, $in_fh, $out_fh); 1 }
         or warn("Error processing \"$qfn\": $@"), next;
      close($out_fh)
         or warn("Error writing to \"$qfn\": $!\n"), next;
   }
} else {
   eval { process(\%map, \*STDIN, \*STDOUT); 1 }
      or warn("Error processing: $@");
   close(\*STDOUT)
      or warn("Error writing to STDOUT: $!\n");
}
```

If you provide no files names beyond the map file, it reads from STDIN and outputs to STDOUT.

If you provide one or more file names beyond the map file, it replaces the files in-place (though it leaves a backup behind).